# Sum of number digits

Tags: python, algorithm

In a challenge i have to find the sum of digits of one number, like: **n = 123** the result should be **1 + 2 + 3 = 6** and if i pass a **k** to the function, the **n** should be the concatanation de **n * k**, like: 
**n = 132, k = 3, n = n * k (123123123)**, and result should be:
**1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 3**.

some of research i think to use is this function:

```
sum = 0
while x > 0:
    rest = n % 10
    n = n // 10
    sum = sum + rest
```

but i think there is a better way to do that.
U guys please can help me, please. Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you think there is a better way? What's wrong with your solution? Are you looking for a more readable solution? A more efficient one? (Or one of many other things "better" can mean)

Comment: i looking for a more efficient one since the string should be gigant, n should be 1<=n<=10ˆ1000000 and k should be 1<=k<=10ˆ5